# Split string(url params string) on basis of "&" while allowing & inside the param value

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have a string like:

```
Id=bzat4e&Name=Gallery: Blitzer: Algebra & Trigonometry, 4e&Year=2016&Code=bzat4e
```

and I want to split it on the basis of `&`, while allowing the `&` inside values.

Basically it is a string of url parameters and I am fetching the value on the basis of key in my JavaScript.

```
I/P 
var paramList = Id=bzat4e&Name=Gallery: Blitzer: Algebra & Trigonometry, 4e&Year=2016&Code=bzat4e

O/P
[Id="bzat4e", Name="Gallery: Blitzer: Algebra & Trigonometry, 4e", Year="2016", Code="bzat4e"]
```

Comment: Note that a 'literal' & in a url param must be encoded with %26.

Comment: Yeah it is, Basically I am fetching the string using 
var paramList = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1))

Comment: @A_01: If you could include the `window.location` in the post, it would really help us in helping you.

Comment: Do you want JS to read your mind in order to decide which `&` are data and which ones are delimiters? Otherwise, how do you expect it to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** to get it as an array

```js
var str = 'Id=bzat4e&Name=Gallery: Blitzer: Algebra & Trigonometry, 4e&Year=2016&Code=bzat4e';
var res = str.split(/&(?=[^=&]+=)/);
console.log(res);
```

---

To convert the array to an object use **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**

```js
var str = 'Id=bzat4e&Name=Gallery: Blitzer: Algebra & Trigonometry, 4e&Year=2016&Code=bzat4e';
var res = str.split(/&(?=[^=&]+=)/).reduce(function(a, b) {
  var spl = b.split('=');
  a[spl[0].trim()] = spl[1];
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

---

For old browser check [polyfill option for reduce() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill).

---

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/rI9yM9/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: No luck man. It creates 2 key-value pair. Like this 
"Name": "Gallery: Blitzer: Algebra ", "Trigonometry, 4e": undefined,
which I dont want

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Not sure why I didn't think of this earlier:

```
var arr = paramList.split(/\b&\b/);
```

Try it out below:

```js
var paramList = "Id=bzat4e&Name=Gallery: Blitzer: Algebra & Trigonometry, 4e&Year=2016&Code=bzat4e";

var arr = paramList.split(/\b&\b/);
var finalArr = [];

arr.forEach(function(pair) {
  var values = pair.split('=');
  var key = values[0];
  var value = values[1];
  var obj = {};
  obj[key] = value;
  finalArr.push(obj);
});

console.log(arr);

console.log(finalArr);
```

Comment: failing for i/p 
classId=sandbox-bzat4e&bltiRequestClassName=Gallery: Blitzer: Algebra &Trigonometry, 4e&schoolYear=2016&bookCode=bzat4e

Comment: @A_01 Yeah it has the same issue, just without the needless extra characters. Let me generate a solution right now.

Comment: @A_01 if every instance of your `&` that you wish to split out is always between word boundaries, you can change the regex to simply `\b&\b`. See my updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for your particular input string using `String.split` function:

```
var str = "Id=bzat4e&Name=Gallery: Blitzer: Algebra & Trigonometry, 4e&Year=2016&Code=bzat4e",
    result = str.split(/(?!\s)[&](?!\s)/);

// now result contains 4 items
console.log(result);  // ["Id=bzat4e","Name=Gallery: Blitzer: Algebra & Trigonometry, 4e","Year=2016","Code=bzat4e"]
```

Comment: Your solution is working fine. Thanks man.
Also I saw some has replied a solution like : split(/&(?!\s)/)
but he removed that one not sure why but his solution is working as well

Comment: I haven't seen that. It doesn't work for you? Maybe, you're testing it on another input string?

Comment: @A_01 That was me. I didn't know if you wanted your solution converted to objects as well, so I removed it. I put it back up with an object solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RegEx to split the string, something like -

`/(?!\s)&(?!\s)/g`

This will split your string based on the "&" character, provided that there are no blank spaces around it.

Check out [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/) for a simple online RegEx editor.

Comment: @A_01 the `(?!\s)` before the `&` actually doesn't prevent a space in front from negating the match. https://regex101.com/r/wR1tJ4/1, which is why I didn't include it.

Comment: @Merlin Thank you for the explanation also can you please lemme know good site/tutorial to learn it. Because I was struggling to create correct regex from past 2 hours on RegEx101 itself :)

Comment: @A_01 regular-expressions.info. If that's too much, regexr.com has a small reference that I found helpful when I first started learning regex. SO has a lot of resources as well on regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/5812121 http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/5812121

Comment: this fails if there is no space after `&`, for eg : `Id=bzat4e&Name=Gallery: Blitzer: AAlgebra &Trigonometry,`

Comment: @A_01 In my opinion, the best way to learn RegEx is to actually write RegEx. Here's an exercise to get you started: try writing a RegEx to validate a phone number. Each country has its own rules, but basically once you understand the logic, it all fits nicely to a pattern. That's what RegEx is all about, finding patterns. Use [regex101](https://regex101.com) for a quick and intuitive RegEx editor. Other then that, Google is your best buddy for RegEx info

Comment: Yeah it seems it will not work in scenerio like "classId=sandbox-bzat4e&bltiRequestClassName=Gallery: Blitzer: Algebra &Trigonometry, 4e&schoolYear=2016&bookCode=bzat4e"  No space between "&Trigno".

Comment: @A_01 Of course not, the pattern is blank space, followed by a "&" character, followed by another blank space. If the pattern changes, you need to change the RegEx.